# What is the backstory regarding the suit of armor at the top of the Munster's staircase?

Tags: tv, dragons, plot-device, the-munsters

Was a backstory ever revealed in any of the TV series or movies regarding who the suit of armor at the head of the stairs under which Spot lives belonged to? If so, what is the backstory?

I ask because a) I'm researching images to build a bigger, better version of a Lego model of the staircase, and b) because Spot "the dog" is a dragon, and St. George came to mind. It seems reasonable that a suit of armor above a dragon's lair would have a backstory. [image: pic]

Comment: Saint George was supposedly martyred in 303 AD, over a thousand years before such suits of armor were being built.  Of course that wouldn't stop TV comedy producers from associating such a suit of armor with St. George.